# How to get commit history for just one file in any branch using GitHub APIs?

Tags: git, rest, github, version-control, github-api

I've tried the following endpoint but it just returns the latest commit. I want to get a list of all the commits in which my file has been involved. Is there any way to do that using github apis?

Endpoint I've tried:
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits/heads/:branch_name?path=file/path.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full history for a specific file path on a specific branch use :

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=path/to/file.py&sha=master
```

For example : https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/commits?path=CREDITS&sha=master